# Python 複数のURLが記載されたCSVファイルから、順にURLを取得してタイトルなどをスクレイピングする方法

Tags: python, web-scraping

一つのページをスクレイピングして、タイトルなどを取得するコードがあります。

```
url = "https://xxxxxxxx"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
title = soup.find("h1").get_text()

print(title)
```

別に、URLが記載されたCSV（URLが1列に縦に並んでいます）があります。

この時、下記のurlの部分にCSVからURLを順に取得していけば良いのはわかるのですが、

```
url = "https:xxxxxx"
```

どのようなコードを書けば良いのかわからず困っております。
アドバイスを頂けませんでしょうか。

コードの全体は以下のようになっております。

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from pathlib import Path
import csv

with open('check_URL.csv',encoding="utf-8") as csv_file :
    a_test = [] 
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
        a_test.append(row[3]) 

del a_test[0]

## ここに何かのコードが必要？

url = "https://xxxxxxxx"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
title = soup.find("h1").get_text()

print(title)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ここは単純に`for`ループで良いのでは？
以下の様な感じですね。

```
urltitlelist = []
for url in a_test:
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find("h1").get_text()
    print(title)
    urltitlelist.append([url,title])

print(urltitlelist)
```

Comment: kunifさん　ありがとうございます。希望通りの事ができました。助かりました。