# URLリストからそれぞれのサイトをスクレイピングする方法

Tags: python, python3, web-scraping

サイトをスクレイピングしてURLリストを作成するコードと、個別サイトの属性のみをスクレイピングするコードが実現できています。

URLリストには個別サイトのURLが記載されているのですが、URLリストのURLに順番に接続しそれぞれスクレイピングするにはどの様にすればよろしいでしょうか？お知恵をお貸しください。よろしくお願いいたします。

・URLを取得するコード

```
import requests, bs4
import codecs
import re

res = requests.get('https://****')
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

elems = soup.select('.threadUrlInMetrics')

for elem in elems:
 with open("abcd.txt", "w") as f:
    print(elems, file=f) 
    file = r'abcd.txt'
with open(file) as f:  
    url_list = f.read()
pattern = "https?://[\w/:%#\$&\?\(\)~\.=\+\-]+"
text = url_list
url_list = re.findall(pattern, text)
print(url_list)
```

・個別のサイトをスクレイピングするコード

```
import requests, bs4
res = requests.get('https://***')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
elems = soup.select('.container')
for elem in elems:
    print(elem)
```

Comment: この記事が参考になるでしょう。[URLリストのtxtを読み込んでスクレイピングして、取得した情報をcsvに保存したい](https://teratail.com/questions/131634) これはいったんリストをファイル化したものを扱っていますが、リストのまま呼び出しても良いわけです。

Comment: そちらのサイトも以前参考にしましたが、リストのまま呼び出すということができず断念しました

Comment: 記事にあるように「個別のサイトをスクレイピングするコード」のURLをパラメータ指定出来るようにして関数化する。「URLリストからforループでURLを1つづつ取り出し、それをパラメータにして関数を呼び出す」の組み合わせで出来ると思うのですが。

Comment: そう言えばしばらく前にこんな記事に回答してましたので参考に。[Python 複数のURLが記載されたCSVファイルから、順にURLを取得してタイトルなどをスクレイピングする方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/59364/26370)

Answer (score 2):

@kunif さんのコメントにある通り、`url_list` に対するfor ループで良いのではないでしょうか

```py
# URLを取得するコード
# ...
url_list = re.findall(pattern, text)


# 個別のサイトをスクレイピングするコード
import requests, bs4

for url in url_list :
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    elems = soup.select('.container')
    for elem in elems:
        print(elem)
```